# Is there any out of box Sitecore Connector available for Sitecore Analytics data automatically to Lookerstudio

Tags: xdb

We are looking for a connector to upload Sitecore Analytics data automatically to Lookerstudio.
Is there any out of box Sitecore Connector available for performing this activity?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, there isn't a dedicated `out-of-the-box` connector within `Sitecore` for the automatic upload of Sitecore Analytics data to `Looker Studio`.

The process of integrating Sitecore Analytics data with Looker Studio generally requires the development of a custom integration, primarily due to the unique characteristics of the data and specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of all the supported integrations at sitecore Connectors and App marketplace: https://www.sitecore.com/products/marketplace

Currently there is no connector supported to integrate data to Looker Studio.

In this situation you would need to create your own connector.